# a logic question about average

Tags: algebra-precalculus, average

the question is the following one: a student attended to a certain number of exams, his grade's average is 25 ( the possible grades are 18-30), in the next exam he gets 30 and his average raises to 26, how many exams he took? the correct answer is 5, but how am i supposed to get it? i tried doing things with the average definition using the summation but i didn't come out with any solution, anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Answer (score 4):

$$\cfrac{25n+30}{n+1}=26$$
$25n$ is the sum of the grades in the $n$ exams.
Multiply both sides by $n+1$
$$25n+30=26(n+1)=26n+26$$
$$25n+30=26n+26$$
$$n=4$$
Where $n$ is how many exams he took before the one he scored 30, so taking that one into account , we have a total of $4+1=5$ exams.

Answer (score 0):

That one exam score was $5$ points above the average but raised the average by just $1$ point. That means it accounts for just $1/5$ of the exams. So it was the fifth exam.